# Could not load type from assembly

Tags: c#, .net

Before you say anything, I have read the previously asked questions about this issue. The answers there did not fix my problem.

It's pretty simple, I guess, if you know the answer. Here's my problem:

I've got a solution with several projects, I'm creating a plugin-based application where I use Reflection to load all assemblies. This part goes fine, I load all my assemblies like so

```
        var filePaths = Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\CustomerServiceModule\", "*.dll", SearchOption.AllDirectories).Where(n => n.Contains("bin"));
        foreach (var f in filePaths)
        {
            Assembly.LoadFile(f);
        }
```

Now I want to create an instance of a type, so I can work with it:

```
            var assembly = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies().Where(a => a.ManifestModule.Name == "Kayako.dll").SingleOrDefault();
            var name = assembly.GetTypes();
            var type = assembly.GetType("Kayako.KayakoData");
            var lol = Activator.CreateInstance(type);
```

This goes badly because inside KayakoData I have this:

```
KayakoService _service = new KayakoService("xxx", "yyy", "zzz");
```

This service is an assembly that works, I've used it before. Version number is fine, there's nothing in the GAC that overrides it, I can't see any errors using Assembly Binding Log Viewer. I still get this error:

> [System.LoadTypeException]{"Could not load type 'KayakoRestAPI.KayakoService' from assembly 'KayakoRestAPI, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'.":"KayakoRestAPI.KayakoService"}

Anyone have any bright ideas? I've been staring myself blind at this. If I remove the service part from KayakoData the whole thing works, but I really need to run the service.

Comment: Have you tried using the fusion log viewer (fuslogvw.exe) to diagnose the issue?

Comment: Where is your the KayakoRestAPI assembly located on your disk relative to the directory of Kayako.KayakoData?

Comment: Are all the assemblies set to AnyCPU?  What other assemblies does this one reference?

Comment: Darin Dimitrov fixed my issue below, thanks a lot for the fast responses though.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Quote from the documentation of the [LoadFile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b61s44e8.aspx) method:

> Use the LoadFile method to load and examine assemblies that have the
>   same identity, but are located in different paths. LoadFile does not
>   load files into the LoadFrom context, and does not resolve
>   dependencies using the load path, as the LoadFrom method does.
>   LoadFile is useful in this limited scenario because LoadFrom cannot be
>   used to load assemblies that have the same identities but different
>   paths; it will load only the first such assembly.

Conclusion: try [LoadFrom](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1009fa28.aspx) in order to load dependent assemblies as well.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to change the version of .dll from assembly info of that project. Then rebuild your solution.